# app is getting crshed showing "UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, key-value-observing

My app getting crashed while navigating back to previous ViewController from a ViewController.
I have registered with observer as:

```
 [tblViewActvityCalender addObserver:self 
                          forKeyPath:@"contentSize" 
                             options:0 
                             context:NULL];
```

and in delloc() method, I'm removing the observer as:

```
[tblViewActvityCalender removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];
```

but still I'm getting app crashed(mostly in ios 8). What I have done wrong ???Thanks in adavnce..
 Crash Log:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7ab75400 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:  (
 Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7a601490>
)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0268f946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02318a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0268f86d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   Foundation                          0x01f496d4 NSKVODeallocate + 379
    4   UIKit                               0x0076459b -[UIView release] + 89
    5   UIKit                               0x0077537a -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 733
    6   UIKit                               0x00793399 -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 84
    7   UIKit                               0x007679bc -[UIView dealloc] + 483
    8   UIKit                               0x0076459b -[UIView release] + 89
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0232ceb1 objc_release + 65
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0232dd32 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 586
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x02571678 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x025a876e __CFRunLoopRun + 2270
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x025a7bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x025a79fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0443824f GSEventRunModal + 192
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x0443808c GSEventRun + 104
    17  UIKit                               0x006fa8b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    18  e-Care                              0x0023311d main + 141
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x035a8ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Can you please paste crash log here?

Comment: I have pasted the crash log in my post.. u can check it...

Comment: is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try following, it may work...

1. Remove observer in viewwilldisappear and also remove table delegates.
2. If you have any running operation which can effect table content size, then stop it or wait for it before you move back to other screen.

Answer (score 0):

Today I face same issue...

Before remove View Or ViewController You need to remove **tableview detaSource, Delegate and tableview from screen and then after remove screen

just add follow code in your .m file.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
     self.tableView.delegate = nil;
     self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
     self.tableView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I hope it will work for you

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you reading http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/

In an object, you use

```
- (void)addObserver:(NSObject *)observer
         forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
            options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options
            context:(void *)context
```

Therefor to remove the observer you should use (you did it)

```
removeObserver:forKeyPath:context
```

However what probably happens is that your UITableView is deallocated before the object (referred as self in your code) is deallocated.
Therefor the crash.

You should ensure that this object unregister before it is deallocated, maybe by doing it within `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: i tried it with viewDidAppear, but result is the same.